# How to get address from UK Postcode?

Tags: postal-code

I have a database, it has table customers one of columns is UK Postcode.
Is it possible to restore full address using postcode ?
I'd like to do it programmatically (c# or other)

Comment: Is the postcode unique to one address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Small user postcodes: collections of (usually) adjacent addresses. A single small user postcode may contain up to 100 addresses, but 15 is a more typical number

Source: [ONS](https://www.ons.gov.uk/methodology/geography/ukgeographies/postalgeography)

Since a post code represents a group of upto 100 addresses, you can't reverse engineer one to a specific address.